# How to insert a cell content into a text area using OpenOffice Calc?

Tags: function, textarea, shapes, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

This is easily doable using Microsoft Excel:

1. Insert > Tex > Text Area > Horizontal Text area.
2. Clicking anywhere inside the sheet and expanding the area.
3. Selecting the formula bar, typing the formula, (i.e. =Sheet1!I10) and voila.

Notice, it is not possible to reference cells that are containing formulas into the text area.
Only cells containing plain text, or numbers can be referenced.

I haven't found any examples using open office calc.
May be it is simply not possible ?